# Changes in ActionBar lifecycle in SDK 17 (4.2)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

It seems that lifecycle for action bar actions has changed in API 17 (Android 4.2).

Before that version `onCreateOptionsMenu()` was called during `onCreate()` but now it seems to be called at least after `onStart()`.

Can someone confirm this and give some explanation and documentation about that changes. It's the only change or are more action bar/activity lifecycle changes?

**EDIT**: There seems to be [an opened issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39721) about this.